# Order a list vertical > horizontal, alphabetically, without blank

Tags: excel, row, alphabetical-sort

I have a list of names in column A, with some blank rows (that need to be blank).
I 'd like to order this list horizontally (row 7, column J to ...), alphabetically and without blanks.
I know how to put the value horizontally (values are in A1:A5, formula in J7) :

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5;MATCH(0,COUNT.IF($I$7:I7,$A$1:$A$5),0))
```

But could you help me to order them alphabetically and without blank please ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy

With data in **A1** through **A5**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(ROW(),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,"<="&$A$1:$A$5)),$A$1:$A$5)
```

and copy down.  Then in **J7** enter:

```
=IF(INDEX($B:$B,COLUMNS($A:A))=0,"",INDEX($B:$B,COLUMNS($A:A)))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Column **B** does the sort.
Row #7 does the horizontal distribution and removal of any zeros.